# Expectation and ratio distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two positive independent random variables, and let $Z =_d X/Y$ where $=_d$ stands for "has the same distribution of".
Let $\psi(\cdot)$ a function such that $\psi(z)=\frac{\psi(x)}{y}$, where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are three positive real number such that $z = x/y$. I want to evaluate the following expectation:
\begin{equation*}
E\{(Z\psi(Z))^2\}.
\end{equation*}
This is my try:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E\{(Z\psi(Z))^2\} & = \int_z (z\psi(z))^2 p_Z(z)dz \\
&= \int_x \frac{x^2}{y^2}\psi\left( \frac{x}{y}\right) ^2 \frac{1}{y} p_Z(x)dx\\
&=\int_x x^2\psi\left( x\right)^2 \frac{1}{y} p_Z(x)dx
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
Now, using the ratio distribution formula [enter link description here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#cite_note-CurtissJ1941On-3), $p_Z(z)$ can be expressed as:
\begin{equation*}
p_Z(z) = \int_y y p_X(yz)p_Y(y)dy, \quad y>0.
\end{equation*}
Then, we have:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E\{(Z\psi(Z))^2\} & = \int_x (x\psi( x))^2 \frac{1}{y} p_Z(x)dx\\
&= \int_x (x\psi( x))^2 \frac{1}{y} \left[ \int_y y p_X(x)p_Y(y)dy \right] dx\\
&= ?
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Van anyone help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: "where $x,y$ and $z$ are positive real numbers with $z=_dx/y$" random real numbers then? Numbers can be looked at as degenerated random variables but then $z=_dx/y$ is the same as $z=x/y$. Btw, why do you write $E_Z$ instead of $E$?

Comment: I used the notation $E_Z$ just to emphasize the fact that this expectation has to be taken wrt Z.

Comment: You should not do that. It only causes confusion. If $\langle\Omega,\mathcal A,P\rangle$ is a probability space and $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ is a random variable then it induces a probability $P_Z$ on $\langle\mathbb R,\mathcal B\rangle$ (i.e. the distribution of $Z$) prescribed by $B\mapsto P(\{Z\in B\})$. In that context $\mathbb E f(Z)$ stands for $\int f(Z(\omega)P(d\omega)$ while $\mathbb E_Z f=\int f(z)P_Z(dz)=\mathbb Ef(Z)$

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll follow you suggestion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found an error in my previous derivation. This is my new try.

Using the ratio distribution formula, $p_Z(z)$ can be expressed as:
\begin{equation*}
p_Z(z) = \int_y y p_X(zy)p_Y(y)dy, \quad y>0.
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
E\{(Z\psi(Z))^2\} & = \int_z (z\psi(z))^2 p_Z(z)dz \\
&= \int_z (z\psi(z))^2 \left[ \int_y y p_X(zy)p_Y(y)dy \right] dz\\
&= \int_z \left[ \int_y (z\psi(z))^2y p_X(zy)p_Y(y)dy \right] dz\\
&= \int_y \left[ \int_z (z\psi(z))^2y p_X(zy)p_Y(y)dz \right] dy \quad \mathrm{ (from \; Fubini's \; Theorem)}\\
&=\int_y \left[ \int_x \left( \frac{x}{y}\psi\left( \frac{x}{y}\right)\right)^2  y p_X(x)p_Y(y)\frac{dx}{y}\right] dy \quad \mathrm{from}\; z=x/y\\
&=\int_y \left[ \int_x  \frac{1}{y^4} (x \psi(x))^2  p_X(x)dx\right] p_Y(y) dy \\
&= E\{Y^{-4}\}E\{(X \psi(X))^2\}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Is this correct?